# how select and get the row id of Cgridvew of yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have been working on yii framework from last 10 days. I done a lot in my project but I stuck with one issue. in the following table when i click the any row it should get the data of selected row in jquery dialog and it should be opened when edit button on the table toolbar is clicked.
[image]

as example when I user click the any row in the listed rows then it is to highlight and if edit button is clicked it should open the  dialog form with selected row data.
here is my code.....

```
      <table class="display" id="dt3">
        <ul class="table-toolbar">
            <li><a href="#" id="create-user"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/icons/basic/plus.png" alt="" /> Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/icons/basic/delete.png" alt="" /> Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="create-user2"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/icons/basic/edit.png" alt="" /> Edit</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
      <table class="display" id="dt4">

          <tr>
        <?php
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Station');
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array
           ( 
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemsCssClass'=>'display',
                    'summaryText'=>'',                   
                    'rowCssClass'=>array('odd gradeX','even gradeC'),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'display'),
                    'columns'=>array(

                        array
                        (   
                            'name'=>'Station Name',       
                            'value'=>'$data->Station_Name',
                        ),

                         array
                        (   
                            'name'=>'Status ',        
                            'value'=>'$data->Status_value',
                        ),

                        array
                        (            
                            'name'=>'Description ',
                            'value'=>'$data->Station_Description',
                        ),
                        array
                        (            
                            'name'=>'Order ID ',
                            'value'=>'$data->OrderID',
                        ),
                        array
                        (            
                            'name'=>'Updated By ',
                            'value'=>'$data->Updated_by',
                        ),
                    ),

                )

                    ); ?>       
     </tr>   
      </table>
          </ul>
        </table>




  <div id="dialog-form" title="Add/Edit Station" class="box-content" style="height: 100px">
       <form action="index.php?r=setting/stations" method="POST">     

      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">Station Name</label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input type="text" name="station_name" />
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">Description</label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input type="text" name="station_description"/>
         </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">Order Id</label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input type="text"name="order_Id" />
         </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">Updated By</label>
        <div class="form-item">
          <input type="text" name="updated_by" />
         </div>
      </div>

     <ul style="float:right;">
         <li style="float:right;"><a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button small green" value="Add  Station"></a></li>
        </ul>

       </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, not a proper answer but maybe you are just looking for [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#selectionChanged-detail)?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `id` property to your `CGridView` configuration:

```
'id' => 'station-grid',
```

then at any point in your javascript code you can get the currently selected rows with:

```
var selected = $('#station-grid').yiiGridView('getSelection');
```

You could for example use the above in a `click` handler on each `tr` of your grid. It's up to you, how to integrate it into your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For all checked row ids we use this

```
 var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("your-grid-id", "selectedIds"); // array of seleted id's from grid
```

If click on row than we can get id like this

```
var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(grid_id);
var id = id[0];
```